# Error when I try to install desktop integration features for Openoffice

Tags: software-installation, openoffice.org

```
peng@peng-ThinkPad-SL410:~$ cd '/home/peng/Downloads/en-US/DEBS/desktop-integration' 
peng@peng-ThinkPad-SL410:~/Downloads/en-US/DEBS/desktop-integration$ sudo dpkg -i *.deb
(Reading database ... 357248 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking openoffice.org-debian-menus (from openoffice.org3.4-debian-menus_3.4-9593_all.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing openoffice.org3.4-debian-menus_3.4-9593_all.deb (--install):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/soffice', which is also in package libreoffice-common 1:3.6.2~rc2-0ubuntu3
/usr/bin/gtk-update-icon-cache
gtk-update-icon-cache: Cache file created successfully.
/usr/bin/gtk-update-icon-cache
gtk-update-icon-cache: Cache file created successfully.
Processing triggers for menu ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme ...
Processing triggers for gnome-icon-theme ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info ...
Unknown media type in type 'all/all'
Unknown media type in type 'all/allfiles'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mms'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mmst'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mmsu'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/pnm'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/rtspt'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/rtspu'
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 openoffice.org3.4-debian-menus_3.4-9593_all.deb
```

Can anyone solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LibreOffice, the office suite that comes preinstalled on Ubuntu is a fork of OpenOffice. That means that basically it's the same program with some modifications. And again that means that they conflict in lots of places.

You can't have both installed at the same time without using some tricks, like installing one from source.

So the easiest way to solve your problems is to uninstall libreoffice before trying to install Openoffice.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved - uninstalling libreoffice-common package is needed, then run again

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

in

> desktop-integration

Should it be OK now ;-)